# Complex Nested has_many / has_one Association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a complex model so I will asks the question first and details below.  I have some cross Model associations.  I think I have them right but I can't drill back-up using the 'through' associations.

Examples:

```
Expenditure.first.budget => OK
ExpenditureItem.first.expenditure.budget => OK
ExpenditureItem.first.project => OK

ExpenditureItem.first.budget => FAIL:

ExpenditureItem Load (0.5ms)  SELECT "expenditure_items".* FROM "expenditure_items" ORDER BY "expenditure_items"."id" ASC LIMIT $1  [["LIMIT", 1]]
NoMethodError: undefined method `klass' for nil:NilClass
from /Users/aximus/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activerecord-6.0.0.rc1/lib/active_record/reflection.rb:790:in `source_reflection'
```

The crazy thing I don't get is why 'ExpenditureItem.first.project' works but 'ExpenditureItem.first.budget' fails when Budget belongs to Project?

I had thought of adding some additional direct foreign keys in here but figured this would work.  I am at the point that I can add them (budget_id, and budget_code_id) but looking to avoid it. I can also add the methods in the models.

I hope I am missing something trivial here or someone can tell me that I can't do this with ActiveRecord.

I also have another layer 'Client' which 'BudgetCode' and 'Project' belongs to but I figure this was complex enough of a question.

Question: why don’t my model associations work as intended?

---

Here is a brief overview of my models

```
class BudgetCode < ApplicationRecord

  has_many :budget_code_items
  has_many :projects

class BudgetCodeItem < ApplicationRecord

  belongs_to :budget_code
```

So it would look like this:

**Budget Code #1**

1. DevOps
2. Development
3. Testing
4. UI/UX

You then create a Budget:

```
class Budget < ApplicationRecord

  belongs_to :project
  belongs_to :budget_code

  has_many :budget_items
  has_many :expenditure_items, through: :budget_code_item
  has_many :expenditures, through: :expenditure_item

class BudgetItem < ApplicationRecord

  belongs_to :budget_code_item
  belongs_to :budget
```

**myapp Budget (Budget #1)**

1. DevOps: $1,000
2. Development $2,000
3. Testing $100
4. UI/UX $10,000

I then have expenditures against that budget:

```
class Expenditure < ApplicationRecord

  belongs_to :vendor
  belongs_to :budget

  has_one :budget_code, through: :budget
  has_one :project, through: :budget
  has_one :client, through: :project

  has_many :budget_items, through: :budget
  has_many :expenditure_items

class ExpenditureItem < ApplicationRecord

  before_save :calculate_amount

  belongs_to :budget_code_item
  belongs_to :expenditure

  has_one :budget_code, through: :budget_code_item
  has_one :budget, through: :expenditure
  has_one :project, through: :budget
```

UPDATE

Here is my related schema.  I took out all the fluff - this shows the relations.

```
  create_table "budget_code_items", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.bigint "budget_code_id", null: false
    t.index ["budget_code_id"], name: "index_budget_code_items_on_budget_code_id"
  end

  create_table "budget_codes", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.bigint "client_id", null: false
    t.index ["client_id"], name: "index_budget_codes_on_client_id"
  end

  create_table "budget_items", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.bigint "budget_code_item_id", null: false
    t.bigint "budget_id", null: false
    t.index ["budget_code_item_id"], name: "index_budget_items_on_budget_code_item_id"
    t.index ["budget_id"], name: "index_budget_items_on_budget_id"
  end

  create_table "budgets", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.bigint "project_id", null: false
    t.bigint "budget_code_id", null: false
    t.index ["budget_code_id"], name: "index_budgets_on_budget_code_id"
    t.index ["project_id"], name: "index_budgets_on_project_id"
  end

  create_table "expenditure_items", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.bigint "budget_code_item_id", null: false
    t.index ["budget_code_item_id"], name: "index_expenditure_items_on_budget_code_item_id"
    t.index ["expenditure_id"], name: "index_expenditure_items_on_expenditure_id"
  end

  create_table "expenditures", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.bigint "budget_id", null: false
    t.boolean "flag_active", default: true
    t.index ["budget_id"], name: "index_expenditures_on_budget_id"
  end
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Hmmm... this must have not saved properly at home on the desktop.

Comment: You have to share what your DB schema looks like and what exact errors you get.

Comment: I updated this.  Its a gross issue / question.  I perhaps could word this better but did my best.  The crazy thing I don't get is why 'ExpenditureItem.first.project' works but 'ExpenditureItem.first.budget' fails when Budget belongs to Project?